# BeautifulSoup changes > to &gt;

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to edit some existing html files, using BeautifulSoup. A problem appears when the DOCTYPE includes an ATTLIST element.

Here's a minimal example.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[<!ATTLIST span bodyref CDATA #IMPLIED>]>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
    <meta content="CA43667" name="dc:identifier"/>
  </head>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, features='html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

The output is

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[<!ATTLIST span bodyref CDATA #IMPLIED>
]&gt;
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
  <meta content="CA43667" name="dc:identifier"/>
 </head>
</html>
```

As seen, the last '>' of DOCTYPE turns into an entity.
With

```py
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

I get

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[<!ATTLIST span bodyref CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
  <meta content="CA43667" name="dc:identifier">
 </head>
</html>
```

Now the DOCTYPE is fine, but the ending slashes in the "meta" elements disappear, and the document won't validate on our system. Other formatter options don't seem to work either.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Note on my deleted answer: Much to my disappointment, the lxml XML parser also doesn’t handle the ATTLIST.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the latest version of BeautifulSoup? I think you'll just need to update BeautifulSoup. Or it may be a weird installation of BeautifulSoup. Try this in your command line:

```
pip uninstall beautifulsoup4
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

As when I run this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[<!ATTLIST span bodyref CDATA #IMPLIED>]>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
    <meta content="CA43667" name="dc:identifier"/>
  </head>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, features='html.parser')
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

This is outputting:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>                                                                                                                                             
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                                                                                                     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"                                                                                                                          
[<!ATTLIST span bodyref CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                                                                                                            
]>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                                                                                                          
 <head>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>                                                                                                 
  <meta content="CA43667" name="dc:identifier"/>                                                                                                                                   
 </head>                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>
```

Which I believe is what you're looking for. I've tested this on an online IDE too and seems to be matching my computer. Here is a link: https://onlinegdb.com/HyzXahzAE

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded BeautifulSoup and have the latest Python version, and still I get the results I described above. How strange. I'm on OSX if that matters.

Comment: @Patrik OSX shouldn't make any difference at all. I'll leave my answer just in case that helps other people. The only other suggestion I can think for you is just to hack it and do a string replace for  `&gt;`